# Connect to WSDL service with PHP script from CLI?

Tags: php, command-line, wsdl, soap-client

I'm having the problem with running PHP script from command line (`php.exe -f <php_file>`) in Windows 7. In the script I'm trying connect to external WSDL service by HTTPS protocol (`$soapClient = new SoapClient($jira_wsdl_url);`).

I'm getting the following error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://...' : failed to
>   load external entity "https://..."

When I run the script from browser then there is no problem connect to WSDL service.

In both cases I'm using the same `php.ini` configuration file.

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY sure you are using the same php.ini, because normally the CLI uses a different physical `php.ini`. Do a `php.exe -i > info.txt` and check the location of the php.ini it says its using.

Comment: I verified it by `php.exe --ini`. It points to the same php.ini file (Loaded Configuration File) as webserver is used. Here is also soap configuration part from info.txt you suggested: `soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400`